# How i can know if the IP host a sites or not by PHP (Reverse IP)

Tags: php, dns, ip

How i can know if the IP host a sites or not by PHP (Reverse IP) ?

For example :

This IP 62.75.138.253 host 5 sites www.earthwar.de , video-4u.com ..ect

If i have and IP i just need to know if it host a websites or not

I think gethostbyaddr is not useful here

Could anyone help please ?

Comment: You want to know what domains are hosted by a specific up address?

Comment: Sorry, I don't 100% understand the question: Do you mean "I have the IP, want the Hostname" or "I have the Hostname, want the IP" ?

Comment: you know its not a 1 to 1 relationship

Comment: i think it's more i have the ip, is the ip a server for website, check port 80 ?

Comment: We don't persecute people because their first language is not English, but unfortunately your question just doesn't make sense and it's too difficult to understand what you want. Try typing your question into [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/) in your own language, then posting the output of that here.

Comment: I'm so sorry guys..my Q has been edited

Answer (score 1):

> How i can know if the IP host a domains or not by PHP ?

There is no single function for this:  It's a non-trivial task. `gethostbyaddr()` will get you the *one* domain name that was configured to be the host name for the IP. That's about all you can get easily.

There are various companies on the web that collect domain names, resolve them, and store the information in a database. It is possible that there are paid services that offer you access to an API, but that doesn't seem to be what you have in mind.

Comment: `will get you the one domain name that was configured to be the host name for the IP` - assuming that one has been configured. `gethostbyaddr()` will query the PTR record for the IP address, and if one does not exist, may return something like `253.138.75.62.in-addr.arpa` - which is actually the lookup term for a reverse lookup, the "query string", if you will.